# Commenting Out in XML

Tags: comments

Is the first set of comment out code below an issue for xml to process since it is put inside of the tag?

```
    <!--Define name="default election policy">
      <Policy name="DefaultToWaive"/>
    </Define-->

     <!-- 
       <Define name="default election policy">
           <Policy name="DefaultToWaive"/>
       </Define>
     -->
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not an issue. It's just interpreted as a comment starting with "Define name=...". It also doesn't matter if you put it on the same line or on separate lines. You could as well write:

```
<!--<Define name="default election policy">
    <Policy name="DefaultToWaive"/>
</Define>-->
```